# Time left format localized 'days', 'hours', 'minutes'

Tags: android, time, localization, format

I have time left in Millis. How to print in format:

"7**d** 12**h** 2**m**" for English localization,
"7**д** 12**ч** 2**м**" for Russian localization
and all other localization

**without use values-ru, values-en, etc**